# Jquery ui autocomplete - combobox - matching the first letter of the second/third word

Tags: regex, combobox, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've searched for this a lot of time, but with no results.
I'm trying to use Jquery UI autocomplete plugin.
I'm using the combobox mode (the example provided here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox).
From what I managed to understand, changing this code (from the example)

`var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );`

with this

`var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );`

ensures I will get autocomplete by the first letter in the first word.
However, supposing I have an array of options like this:

```
<option value="">Auto Skin</option>
<option value="">Score</option>
```

and typing letter 's', it will automatically show only "Score" option.

How could I change the regexp to get both results, since option "Auto Skin" has the word "Skin" which also start with letter 's'?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the regex pattern `^` which matches the start of the string, use the regex pattern `\b` to match a word boundary.

```
var matcher = new RegExp("\\b" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
```

More information [here](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/217-how-to-match-whole-words-with-a-regular-expression/).

Comment: I tried this but it's not working. Where should I put this, in  source: function( request, response ) ?

Comment: I mean, var matcher = new RegExp("\ " + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" ); completes second, third words, but doesn't autocomplete the first.

Comment: Use `\b` for a word boundary, not `\ `

Comment: But using var matcher = new RegExp("\b" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" ); doesn't work at all, I get no autocomplete results.

Comment: Oops, forgot the backslash needed to be escaped too.  Updated the code in my answer, should be `\\b`